# CHCSVWriter Unicode Problem

Tags: macos, nsarray

I having problem using `CHCSVwriter` to export my arrays to CSV or excel file.

I have several `Arrays` that are in `Persian language` ( it's localized and this must be UTF-8, at least in windows ).

With using CHCSVWriter ( [thanks, Dave](http://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) ) I am able to do export my arrays into CSV file BUT not with default settings.

Because of my array encodings ( UTF8 Did not work , I don't know why !! ) but changing CHCSVwriter.m I am able to write the files with my localized language.

I have a strange Problem :

1- If I use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` then I have one standard Comma separated CSV file that is able to be opened with Excel very well with correct columns separation BUT table cells are in unknown encoding ( I am using persian language)

2- If I use `NSUTF16StringEncoding` then I have a CSV file that whole columns of each row writes into one column ! but the language and encoding is right ! the strange thing is that commas are NOT detectable for excel and it's open a table with just One column that each row contains whole columns that I designed to be separated with commas that are existing there !!!

Also, I have another problem that I don't find a way to set encoding for CHCSVWriter and I have to change it manually from CHCSVWriter.m file !
part of CHCSVWriter.m:

```
- (void)_writeString:(NSString *)string {
//  if (encoding == 0) {
//      encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
        encoding = NSUTF16StringEncoding;
//}
```

And part of my code :

```
    NSString * tempFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sellExport.csv"];
    NSString * tempFile =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];

    NSLog(@"Writing to file: %@", tempFile);

    error = nil;
     CHCSVWriter *sellExporting = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:tempFile atomic:NO];


    [sellExporting writeLine];
    for (int i = 0; i<=[purchaseCodes count] ; i++) {


        [sellExporting writeLineOfFields:[purchaseCodes objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseDates objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseCarBrands objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseCarSystems objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseCarModels objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseCarColors objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseCarChassis objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseCustomerNames objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseSharedNames objectAtIndex:i],[purchaseTotals objectAtIndex:i],[sellCodes objectAtIndex:i],[sellCustomerNames objectAtIndex:i],[sellDates objectAtIndex:i],[sellTotals objectAtIndex:i],[sellProfits objectAtIndex:i],[sellShareProfits objectAtIndex:i],nil];
        }
    [sellExporting closeFile];
    [sellExporting release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody could resolve my problem,

I found that **Unicode encoding** is not very well supported with **Microsoft Excell** ( mac ).
In other hand, because of this fact that I'm using **Perisan** language for my data entries so I have to use `NSUTF16StringEncoding` ( why `UTF8StringEncoding` didn't work ? I don't know !! ) and when I open the .csv file I have all my data in just one column ( I have 16 column ) and **Microsoft Excell** can not detect **comma** (,) as separation delimiter !!!

Anyway, now, I am able to open the **UTF16** Encoded **CSV** file using **NeoOffice** or **OpenOffice** that well supported Unicode .csv files without any problem !

So, this all about **Microsft** not **Dave deLong**'s CHCSVWriter. ( thank you Dave, Again )

this my 5th question that I solved by myself !!!

Thank you all anyway.